# How do I find whether a filtered BindingSource contains an item from the underlying DataSet?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, combobox, bindingsource

Apologies in advance for the slightly wooly descriptions of what's going on. I'm pretty sure of what I've done, I'm just not sure of the proper terminology. I'll do my best to respond to any requests for clarification as soon as possible.

I've got a databound query in my application which is querying the "Customers" table in our database. I've created this directly from the ComboBox's datasource creator in the Design view.

Various bits of code created in the designer include:

```
Me.CustomerBindingSource.DataSource = Me.CustomerDataSet
Me.ComboBox_Customers.DataSource = Me.CustomerBindingSource
```

What I've done in the first stage of developing this feature is to show my users a ComboBox showing a specific subset of the customer list by applying a filter to the BindingSource.

```
Me.CustomerBindingSource.Filter = "someColumn = 3"
```

What I want to do on a second pass is to allow the users to type a specific bit of information into a textbox and check whether it appears in `Me.CustomerDataSet` like so:

```
Dim x As IEnumerable(Of CustomerDataSet.customerRow) = From cust In Me.CustomerDataSet.customer Where cust.custno.Trim = "test"
If x.Count <> 0 Then
```

**The Actual Question**

At this point, I have a `customerRow` object. I want to check whether this customerRow object appears in the list presented to users in `Me.ComboBox_Customers` via the filtered `Me.CustomerBindingSource`. `Me.CustomerBindingSource` does not (directly) contain `customerRow` objects, it contains `Object` objects.

How do I find out whether `Me.CustomerBindingSource` contains the customerRow object at whatever lower level?

Also

Once I've determined that `Me.CustomerBindingSource` contains the item, how do I select that entry in the ComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I've settled on is to call a function which basically does:

```
For Each customerIn As DataRowView In Me.CustomerBindingSource
    If customerIn .Row Is x(0) Then
        Me.ComboBox_Customers.SelectedItem = customerIn 
    End If
Next
`Otherwise do nothing
```

So the `Is` comparison I was looking for was `Me.CustomerBindingSource.Item(index).Row` because although `Me.CustomerBindingSource` only contains `Object` objects, they're all objects of type `DataRowView`, which have a `Row` property, which contains the `DataRow` objects I've already retrieved from my LINQ query of `Me.CustomerDataSet`.

If anyone has any answers to this question more awesome than a `For` loop, I'd love to learn them.